# How can I reinstall Apache HTTPD after deleting some of the configuration files?

Tags: apt, apache2

I recently was messing around with my Apache config and wanted to reinstall so I could start from fresh. I followed some forum posts about reinstalling the `apache2` package and this ended up deleting my `/etc/apache2` folder.

Now matter how many things I try I can't seem to do a full wipe of the Apache install and then reinstall. `sudo apt-get install apache2` or `reinstall` doesn't do anything. I can't seem to remove it using Synaptic either.

Is there anything I can do to have a fresh Apache install on my computer again?

Comment: /etc/apache2/envvars is in apache2.2-common, have you reinstalled that package too? Like with command `sudo apt-get --reinstall install apache2.2-common`

Answer (score 82, accepted):

To replace configuration files that have been deleted, without purging the package, you can do

```
sudo apt-get -o DPkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" --reinstall install apache2
```

To fully remove the apache2 config files, you should

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2
```

which will then let you reinstall it in the usual way with

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Purge is required to remove all the config files - if you delete the config files but only remove the package, then this is remembered & missing config files are not reinstalled by default.

Comment: This also doesn't work. It says that apache2 is already installed and the purge doesn't remove the config file in etc/apache2. In fact the purge complains that it can't envvars too.

Comment: Has reinstalling apache2.2-common with the option about to replace missing conf files worked for you?

Comment: Almost a year later and found this, thank you very much.

Comment: helped a lot, but package apache2.2-common doesn't exist anymore....did the same sequence just with package apache2

Comment: Not tested with Ubuntu, but under Debian to restore config files which are managed by `ucf` the `--force-confmiss` option won't work, you have to use `sudo UCF_FORCE_CONFFMISS=1 apt-get --reinstall install [pkgname]`.

Comment: `apt-get purge apache2` works in Debian 8!

Comment: It happened to me that I had the file but was empty. It's important that the file to recover doesn't exists so it's installed again.

Answer (score 6):

run the following command first

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2 apache2-utils
```

then run

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

it worked for me

Comment: This will delete all your apache configs. :(

Comment: @tokam Yes, see the question.

Comment: This work and delete apache conf files. sites-enable and sites-available directories and conf files are kept!

Answer (score 2):

Remove Apache2 files...

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2*
```

Clean install

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install apache2.2-common
sudo apt-get --reinstall install apache2
```

Comment: right, you need to remove all related packages in order to reinstall config files

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
apt-get -f install
```

then run

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Edit:  or possibly

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2
sudo apt-get install apache2
```