# How do I restore /etc/init.d/nginx after removal?

Tags: services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I replace missing configuration files after removing a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26228/how-can-i-replace-missing-configuration-files-after-removing-a-package)

I have installed nginx with apt-get. Than I removed it. I also manually removed `/etc/init.d/nginx`. After I installed it again with apt-get, it didn't create `/etc/init.d/nginx`. So service nginx doesn't work anymore. Is is possible to force apt-get to create this file again?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like somehow a record remains of that file, which counts as a configuration file (apparently), so a simple apt-get remove doesn't get rid of that record; thus, when reinstalling, apt-get tries to be nice and not overwrite a configuration file (which doesn't exist).

To recreate it, first uninstall using purge to remove even configuration files and records:

```
apt-get purge nginx nginx-common nginx-full
```

then reinstall:

```
apt-get install nginx
```

Comment: Please, be careful following this advice **AS IT ALSO REMOVES ALL THE CONFIGURATION** in */etc/nginx*. Be sure to make a copy beforehand.