# how reinstall apache2?

Tags: installation, apache2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I replace missing configuration files after removing a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26228/how-can-i-replace-missing-configuration-files-after-removing-a-package)

**I have a problem in my apache2:**
And i exec `sudo aptitude purge apache2`, but in 
*/etc/* the folder *apache2* persist, after this, i move the *apache2* to *apacheold*, and exec `sudo aptitude install apache2`, and this has been installed the command "apache2" but in the */etc/*, the folder *apache2* is not exist

Answer (score 32):

First:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove apache2
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then installing apache2 is as simple as:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

To test it:

```
lynx "http://localhost"
```

- [More information on configuration Apache (Ubuntu 13.10)](https://help.ubuntu.com/13.10/serverguide/httpd.html)

Comment: Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/5.5.38 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3

Comment: Welcome to phpMyAdmin

Error

MySQL said: Documentation
Cannot connect: invalid settings.
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.
Retry to connect

Comment: See if you have your mysql up and running

Comment: i have followed this steps it says "This site can’t be reached" for localhost although I have tried many solution. Same results obtained and neigther apache2 default configuration loaded nor the custom one

Comment: Try your local ip instead.