# How can I restore the default /etc/apache2 and default apache2 files?

Tags: installation, apache2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I replace missing configuration files after removing a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26228/how-can-i-replace-missing-configuration-files-after-removing-a-package)

My /etc/apache2 folder has been deleted, is there a way to restore the defaults of all files for apache2?

I've tried 
    sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2
    sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2

Any way to do this?

thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Found this:

```
apt-get install --reinstall apache2.2-common
```