# Can't install Apache HTTPD after deleting original folders

Tags: installation, apache2

I had some problems with Apache, so I removed the entire folder from /etc , /var... now the command:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

doesn’t work, I guess because there are no apache folder anymore. So:

- Do I have to download it?
- Any other solution?

Comment: can you post the error message you get when trying to reinstall? can you confirm exactly which folders you deleted? my current guess would be to uninstall the apache2 package via apt, then try and install again

Comment: see also https://askubuntu.com/questions/111770/how-reinstall-apache2 and the linked duplicate - if they help, mark your question as a duplicate

Comment: I followed the given link's command line, and here's what I got     
/etc/init.d/apache2: 51: .: Can't open /etc/apache2/envvars

Comment: sounds similar to the discussion between seadowg and ajmitch in the comments to this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/26247/7146 - it would help if you edited your question to include exactly what you type in and what you get out in a formatted fashion (rather than in the comments)

Comment: It works! ... thank you so much d3vid!!

Comment: great! I'm requesting this question is closed as a duplicate, and tweaking the other title to (hopefully) make it more discoverable - welcome to AskUbuntu :D

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall it via apt-get with

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2
```

or

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2
```

If it doesn't help - provide full output of that commands.

Comment: after these commands I add sudo apt-get install apache2 ...Output:Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
apache2 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
/*that's all normally it should be longer */

Comment: Does removal command exited without errors?

Apache2 catalogs still missing?

You may try

    **sudo apt-get install apache2 --reinstall**